# Particular TextView with Multiple Drawables

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

In my *Linear layout* (orientation: vertical), I have a TextView setted like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="TEXT-TEXT-TEXT"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:gravity="right"/>
```

I need to put two Drawable inside this TextView to make a result like this **[first drawable] text [second drawable] text**.

I have tried a simple android:drawableStart but it put the image at very left of the Layout, and I also need another image.

There is some elegant solution to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: By using **compound drawables**, you could have this schema: `[first drawable] text text [second drawable]` Or simply use **2** TextViews, like `[first drawable] text` and (next to it) `[second drawable] text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by 2 different ways, both are based on using a LinearLayout with multiples components instead of your single Textview.

**Using TextViews & ImageViews**

This way offers a fine tuning of each components (texts and images) individually but is a bit longer.

Replace your TextView by:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_upload"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEXT 1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_upload"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEXT 2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Using only TextViews**

This one is shorter (only 2 components) and use compound drawables.

Replace your TextView by:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:drawableStart="@android:drawable/ic_menu_upload"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEXT 1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <TextView
        android:drawableStart="@android:drawable/ic_menu_upload"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEXT 2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```